# xsd.exe not finding type declarations

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I'm attempting to generate class files from the XSD files provided on the IRS website:

https://www.irs.gov/businesses/corporations/fatca-xml-schemas-and-business-rules-for-form-8966

schema documents downloadable here: https://www.irs.gov/pub/fatca/fatcaxml_v2.0.zip

(FATCAXML_v2.0 (25KB) - Main schema for FATCA reporting.)

The zip file contains 4 documents:

- FatcaXML_v2.0.xsd
- isofatcatypes_v1.1.xsd
- oecdtypes_v4.2.xsd
- stffatcatypes_v2.0.xsd

In the first document, FatcaXML_v2.0.xsd, there are 3 xsd:import nodes which appear to reference the 3 other xsd documents.

When attempting to generate my classes using xsd.exe against FatcaXML_v2.0.xsd, I get multiple errors about types not being declared, e.g:

```
Schema validation warning: Type 'urn:oecd:ties:stffatcatypes:v2:StringMax200_Type' is not declared. Line 259, position 5.
```

However, I do see a declaration for this type in stffatcatypes_v2.0.xsd (which was imported to the top of 'FatcaXML_v2.0.xsd') :

```
<xsd:simpleType name="StringMax200_Type">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>Defines a string with maximum length of 200
    </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:minLength value="0"/>
        <xsd:maxLength value="200"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

How I get xsd.exe to recognize these type definitions?

thanks in advance

Comment: What are the `schemaLocation` attributes in the `<import >` elements?

Comment: <xsd:import namespace="urn:oecd:ties:isofatcatypes:v1" schemaLocation="isofatcatypes_v1.1.xsd"/>
 <xsd:import namespace="urn:oecd:ties:stffatcatypes:v2" schemaLocation="stffatcatypes_v2.0.xsd"/>
 <xsd:import namespace="urn:oecd:ties:stf:v4" schemaLocation="oecdtypes_v4.2.xsd"/>   : the files are all in the same folder

Comment: And all the schemas are co-located in the same folder? In which case, try specifying each schema file on the command line.

Comment: Yes the files are all in the same folder; I'll try to specify all the input files in a single command

Comment: OK, although if they are I wouldn't have thought you needed to. Still, if it works!

Comment: I don't suppose you've got something like Altova XMLSpy that you could use to load and validate them?

Comment: just as a side note - I managed to generate the python classes with generateDS.py so if I still don't get this to work I'll swap out the xml processing portion of the project with a python script

Comment: @spodger man, it's weird - I suspect there is a problem with the schema - there seems to be a duplicate "AddressFree" child for a node - but the government needs me to submit data in this format, so I don't have alot of flexibility to correct or change the schema in any way. Other entities managed to get it done (I've heard) so I presume it's more a matter of me not doing the right thing and not their schema being bad. Oh and I looked into that software, that's waaayyy over my budget on this

Comment: Weird that it's ok with python! What exactly is your XSD command line? I think you may need to specify the files in order lowest to highest, if you see what I mean.

Comment: @spodger, yea I'm going to give that a try next re: dependent ordering - Have to leave it alone now for a little bit; Will let you know if it works!

Comment: Ok, good luck!!

Comment: @spodger you were right! this command worked:   xsd stffatcatypes_v2.0.xsd oecdtypes_v4.2.xsd isofatcatypes_v1.1.xsd FatcaXML_v2.0.xsd /dataset /out:c:\tmp\classout\

Comment: and by worked I mean it stopped complaining about the custom types; now it's complaining about that duplicate addressfree :-/ ... but this question is answered!

Comment: last note: this worked without error, despite the weird addressfree column: xsd stffatcatypes_v2.0.xsd oecdtypes_v4.2.xsd isofatcatypes_v1.1.xsd FatcaXML_v2.0.xsd /c /out:C:\tmp\classout (generating classes instead of a dataset)

Comment: Excellent. I'll cobble together an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get XSD.exe to 'honour' schemas imported using the

```
<xsd:import namespace="importNamespace" schemaLocation="schema.xsd"/>
```

declaration, the schemas need to be located in the same folder and you need to specify all of them in the command line. They should also be specified in order of use from the base schema to the parent. So if you have a schema, `parent.xsd` which imports `child.xsd` which in turn imports `base.xsd` then your command line needs to be as follows

```
xsd base.xsd child.xsd parent.xsd [options]
```

**N.B.** the schemas may not need to all be in the same location but if not I suspect that the relative location(relative to where you are running XSD which should be in the folder of the primary schema) would need to be specified on the command line for each schema and should probably match the `<import schemaLocation` attribute but I'm not in a position to confirm this at the moment.